# fetchPolicy option: "no-cache" does not work in useQuery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

this my code

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(HeaderPage.query, {
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache"
  });
```

when i use fetchPolicy: "no-cache". Repeated request does not go.

What is the reason why only once a request is made ?

Comment: what do you mean about Repeated request ?

Comment: when the component is first built, the request is sent and the second time the request does not occur

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the `useQuery` hook, the query you provide is fetched when the component *mounts*. Whether it's fetched from the server or the cache will depend on your cache policy (and whether there's anything in the cache). After the query is initially fetched, it will only be fetched again if either 1) the options passed to the hook change or 2) you call the `refetch` function returned by the hook. The query will not be fired again just because the component rerenders -- this would result in excessive requests and an infinite render loop.

Comment: maybe [tobacco](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3315) ?